# How to set a formula in app script that can be manually edited in the sheet

Tags: populate

I have some formula that I want to write in App Script because I need to populate the functions. The problem is I can't figure out what formula can make it editable in the sheet because some can't be automated and needs to be manually inputted in the sheet. For example I am using a list of percentages for index match but there are times that the percentage is different from what it should be based on the list, so I need to input it manually. Would there be any way to do it?